# if/else conditional logic vs exception handling

Tags: oracle, plsql, refactoring

If I have to run a PL/SQL code based on the release version of a product, is it better to add an if/else conditional logic or handle it via exceptional handling?

```
IF release_version > 5 THEN
    execute some SQL query only for release > 5 because a certain column was only introduced in ver 6;
ELSE
    execute another SQL query;
END IF;
```

Comment: If you're going to have a static SQL statement that references a column that might not exist, you're going to have a problem.  The entire block won't compile if the column isn't there so the ELSE wouldn't be able to run.  Doesn't matter if you have an IF/ ELSE or an exception block, the entire block will fail to compile.  If that's really the situation you're in, you could potentially look at conditional compilation (depending on your Oracle version) but that may add some additional complexity to your process.

Comment: I'm using EXECUTE IMMEDIATELY and it hasn't complained about the non-existing column. Is that approach okay?

Comment: Why your PL/SQL codebase can't be in sync with your table structures ? If the table is different for release 5 and 6 why your PL/SQL code can't be ?

Comment: Either way, using exception handling for business logic is not really ideal, although it has its place. For example in a release script that needs to add a column, it can be more efficient to just attempt the operation and handle the 'already exists' exception than to code an existence checker. So it all depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to use "On Conditional Compilation"

[Conditional Compilation in Oracle](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/conditional-compilation-10gr2)

That way only the code needed for your version is compiled.

```
create or replace package product as
   version   number := 5;
end;
/

create or replace procedure compiletime as
begin
   $if product.version=5 $then
      dbms_output.put_line ('I am version 5');
   $elsif product.version=6 then
      dbms_output.put_line('I am version 6');
   $else
      dbms_output.put_line('Some other version');
   $end
end compiletime;
```

In this example only "**dbms_output.put_line ('I am version 5');**" would be compiled. Rest would be discarded.